# Cant copy files from minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, scp

I have setup a kubernetes cluster locally using minikube and want to copy a file from the minikube to my local machine.
I am able to ssh into minikube successfully and run command but the scp command is timing out.

Commands followed

```
scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip):/home/docker/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/newconfig.json
```

and I am getting the following error message

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.49.2 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to copy files from container to local machine you can use follow command to do the same # Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar

Answer (score 0):

Use ‘**KUBECTL CP**’ to Copy the files and directories from a Kubernetes Container [POD] to the local host and vice versa.

> Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

```
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```